# How to get the limit of a rule

Tags: equation-solving, functions, rule

When using the `FindRoot` function on a certain function, the returned object is a rule. Specifically, the outcome is `{t -> 5.19188}`. My question is how I could retrieve the `5.19188` value from this answer, or if this is even possible.

Comment: try `t /. sol` where `sol ={t -> 5.19188}`. Or,  just  `sol[[1, -1]]` .

Comment: Or (for completeness) a kludgy approach:  `{t -> 5.19188}[[1, 2]]`

Comment: Specifically, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/12

Answer (score 0):

This is done with the `ReplaceAll` command's infix notation syntax `/.`

```
sol={t->5.19188}
t/.sol
(*5.19188*)
```